# Setting Up Simple Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I have attempted to set these up but want to make sure I'm on the right track. Any help is appreciated!

Dante can only invite 8 people to his birthday, but has 13 friends he’d like to invite. Eight of his friends are boys and five are girls. If Dante randomly selects 8 people, determine the probability for each scenario.

1. **Dante does not invite any girls**
   $\binom{13}{8}$ Randomly selecting 8 people
   $\binom{8}{8}$ not girls
   = $\binom{13}{8}$   $\binom{8}{8}$
2. **Dante invites an equal number of boys and girls**
   This would mean out of the 8 people, 4 need to be boys and 4 girls.
   $\binom{13}{8}$ Selection
   $\binom{8}{4}$ boys
   $\binom{5}{4}$ girls
   = $\binom{13}{8}$ ? $\binom{8}{4}$ * $\binom{5}{4}$

Comment: Note that a *probability* is a value between zero and one.  You are counting outcomes, which is a good start, but the probability is obtained as a ratio of the *favorable* outcomes to all *possible* outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to put the total number of possibilities in denumerator and the number of desired possibilities in the numerator.

1. $$\frac{\binom{8}{8}}{\binom{13}{8}}$$
2. $$\frac{\binom{8}{4}\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{13}{8}}$$